# T-SQL How to configure Group by so that specific values would be correctly shown

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

My current T-SQL query provides the following results:

Query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT SubscriberID, sum(valueMB) as ValuesMB
FROM dbo.InternetNetwork
GROUP BY SubscriberID
),
CTE2 AS (
SELECT ab.planID, a.SubscriberID, MAX(ValuesMB) as MaximumValue
FROM CTE AS a
left join 
Subscriber as ab on a.SubscriberID= ab.SubscriberID
GROUP BY ab.planID, a.SubscriberID
)
select *
FROM CTE2 as b
ORDER BY b.MaximumValue desc
```

Output:

```
planID | SubscriberID | MaxValue
19           1555       97536.00
18           3528       97478.00
2            4029       93413.00
```

Query #2:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT SubscriberID, sum(valueMB) as ValuesMB
FROM dbo.InternetNetwork
GROUP BY SubscriberID
),
CTE2 AS(
SELECT ab.planID, MAX(ValuesMB) as MaximumValue
FROM CTE AS a
left join 
Subscriber as ab on a.SubscriberID= ab.SubscriberID
GROUP BY ab.planID
)
SELECT pl.OperatorID, MAX(b.MaximumValue) as Super
FROM CTE2 as b
left join
Plan as pl on b.planID= pl.planID
GROUP BY pl.operatorID
ORDER BY pl.operatorID
```

Output #2:

```
OperatorID | Value
1            93413.00
2            86017.00
3            97536.00
```

I would like to also include a subscriberID, but I'm unable to figure out a way to do so, as the only way to do it, is including in the last SELECT and adding to GROUP BY, which when done, makes a mess of a result which is not accurate.

My desired output:

```
 OperatorID | Value     | SubscriberID
    1         93413.00    4029
    2         86017.00    164
    3         97536.00    1544
```

internet network data:

```
SubscriberID    ValuesMB
1               28
1               27
2               27
2               27
2               27
3               29
3               28
3               27
3               27
4               27
4               27
4               29
```

Subscriber Data:

```
SubscriberID    PersonID    PlanID
1               1           3
2               2           10
3               2           6
4               3           14
5               3           1
6               4           18
7               5           5
8               5           1
9               5           9
10              5           16
11              6           13
12              6           13
13              6           20
14              6           16
15              7           4
```

Plan data

```
PlanID  OperatorID
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       2
6       2
7       2
8       2
9       2
10      2
11      2
12      3
13      3
14      3
15      3
16      3
17      3
18      3
19      3
20      3
```

The tables are somewhat like this related InternetNetwork-> Subscriber -> Plan. InternetNetwork contains how much each Subscribed has used. Each Subscriber has Plan associated with him. Each Plan contains a different Operator, there are only three. I wish to list all three operators, the data transferred by the subscriber of the plan that has the operator and Subscriber ID.

Comment: Can you please supply the sample data you used to generate the above output.

Comment: Yes, One moment.

Comment: what version of mssql are you using? There's a good chance using windowing function PARTITION BY might work better in this case

Comment: So how do you come from `subscriberid` 1 .. 15 to a desired result of `4029` or `1544`?

Comment: I don't think that it matters, the data which is given by my outputs is too big to be added, therefore the data which is given here would provide of course different output, but the logic would remain the same. The most important structure I think is specified.

Comment: And in your first result you have a `planid` of `19` but I don't see that anywhere in your subscriber data? Maybe you could describe verbally how `subscriber data` and `plan data` lead to your desired output?

Comment: Well, it matters. Because without understanding of how your input leads to your desired output how would anybody be able to help you? If your data is to big to be posted as a whole, please make your reduced example at least consistent ...

Comment: I will try my best to do so. The tables are somewhat like this related InternetNetwork-> Subscriber -> Plan. InternetNetwork contains how much each Subscribed has used.
Each Subscriber has Plan associated with him. Each Plan contains a different Operator, there are only three.

Comment: And what is the `value` of `93413.00`? The total sum of data transfered by an operator for all subscribers, or just for a single subscriber, the maximum of all subscribers? Add if you add additional descriptions, please add them *to the question*  and don't bury them in the comments

Comment: And what is the value of 93413.00? Is the total data transferred by a single subscriber, I wish to specify the SubscriberID, Plans Operator, and the value which was transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions allow you to have fields in your select along with aggregate functions. You can do something like this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT I.SubscriberID, 
         S.PlanID,
         SUM(ValuesMB) OVER(PARTITION BY i.SubscriberID)as ValuesMB
  FROM dbo.InternetNetwork I
  JOIN Subscriber S
      ON I.SubscriberID = S.SubscriberID
),
CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT p.operatorID,
         a.SubscriberID,     
         a.ValuesMB,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.operatorID ORDER BY a.ValuesMB DESC) as rn
  FROM CTE a
  join [Plan] P
    on a.planID = P.planID
)
SELECT operatorID,
       ValuesMB,
       SubscriberID
FROM CTE2
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This works as desired.